# Unread marks in Xpages views are indented ? Any fix

Tags: xpages

Put in unread marks in a view in Xpages and the column is indented very very oddly. 
Searched google and found this document:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1LO78976

However, when I try to log in and actually see the document, I can never get to document to open. IBM doesn't have unreads working in Xpages???

My apologies.

[image]

Code is here:

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="99" id="ProjectsWorking"
                    viewStyle="width:99.0%" rowClasses="oddrow, evenrow"
                    var="viewEntry" showUnreadMarks="true">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                            layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="ProjectsWorking"
                            viewName="ProjectsWorking">
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn26"
                        style="width:15.00px" rendered="false">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                                id="viewColumnHeader26" style="width:15.00px" rendered="false">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:this.iconSrc><![CDATA[#{javascript:var unr = viewEntry.getRead();
if (unr)
{return ""}
else
{"/unread.gif"}}]]></xp:this.iconSrc>
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:""}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Priority"
                        id="viewColumn1" style="width:15.00px" showCheckbox="true">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Priority"
                            id="viewColumnHeader1"
                            style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;width:15.00px"
                            sortable="true" showCheckbox="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ProjectName"
                        id="viewColumn2" displayAs="link" style="width:150.00px">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Project"
                            id="viewColumnHeader2"
                            style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline"
                            sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn19"
                        columnName="ProjectCoordinator" style="width:50.00px">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                                id="viewColumnHeader19" value="Project  Manager" sortable="true"
                                style="font-weight:bold">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn18"
                        columnName="ITCoordinator" style="width:50.00px">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                                id="viewColumnHeader18" sortable="true" style="font-weight:bold"
                                value="IT Lead">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Scope" id="viewColumn3"
                        style="width:35.00px">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Scope"
                            id="viewColumnHeader3"
                            style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline"
                            sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn12"
                        columnName="IsWorking" style="width:35.00px">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                                id="viewColumnHeader12" value="Working?"
                                style="font-weight:bold" sortable="true">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="DesiredCompletionDate"
                        id="viewColumn4" style="width:50.00px">
                        <xp:this.converter>
                            <xp:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"></xp:convertDateTime>
                        </xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader
                            value="Desired Completion Date" id="viewColumnHeader4"
                            style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline"
                            sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn5"
                        columnName="ProjectStatus" style="width:75px">
                        <xp:this.facets>
                            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                                id="viewColumnHeader5" value="Status"
                                style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline"
                                sortable="true">
                            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        </xp:this.facets>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                </xp:viewPanel>
```

Comment: Your code and a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I have added screen shot and code.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation is caused by

```
.xspDataTableRowRead td:first-child {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Use application theme `OneUI V3.0.2` instead of `OneUI V2.1` (or earlier). Then there is no indentation anymore.

If you can't change application theme then overwrite this css setting with

```
.xspDataTableRowRead td:first-child {
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```